How to convert a list of Pydantic objects to a JSON string
The following code successfully converts a list of UserSQLAlchemyModel to a list of UserPydanticModel:
users_from_db = session.scalars(select(UserSQLAlchemyModel)).all()
users = TypeAdapter(list[UserPydanticModel]).validate_python(users_from_db)

Now how can I convert users to a JSON string? I have noticed using dump_json instead of validate_python works but the problem is the exclude parameter of dump_json has no effect and there is no documentation about dump_json. Also I really like to know if dump_json skips validation or not.
My solution using directly Pydantic's to_json:
from pydantic_core import to_json

users_json = to_json(
    [UserPydanticModel.model_dump(exclude=('password'))
    for user in users]
)

But I don't know if it is the right way to do it. And it is sad that Pydantic does not provide a simple solution for array of objects.
Why I don't use Python json.dumps()? I don't like to deal with not JSON serializable error.

I would like to know the answer too. But it didn't come, so I did my own experiments. Hope it helps.
Q1: Does dump_json() skips validation?
A1: It looks like it just serializes. To get a correct output I had to use the TypeAdapter twice: first time to valdiate, then to serialize.
Q2: Problem with exclude=
A2: Please read the Advanced include and exclude
Below is my little test program with mocked data:
from pydantic import BaseModel, TypeAdapter

class UserPydanticModel(BaseModel):
    name: str 
    passwd: str 
    demo: bool = True

users_from_db = [dict(name=f'usr{i}', passwd=f'pwd{i}') for i in range(3)]

ta = TypeAdapter(list[UserPydanticModel])
users = ta.validate_python(users_from_db)
dumped = ta.dump_json(users, exclude={'__all__': 'passwd'})

print(dumped)

# b'[{"name":"usr0","demo":true},{"name":"usr1","demo":true},{"name":"usr2","demo":true}]'


Firstly, import json
Convert the list to a list of your UserPydanticModel:
users = [UserPydanticModel.from_orm(user) for user in users_from_db]

To exclude field in json:
json_str = [user.json(exclude={'some_field_to_exclude'}) for user in users]

If you want to convert the list of JSON strings to a single JSON string:
final_json_str = json.dumps(json_str)

If you have more sample code snippets, that would be even better.

Your JSON array will be double encoded; not an ideal result.
